# Citrix XenDesktop - Application makes desktop launch

Tags: citrix, xendesktop

When I launch an application in Citrix Receiver for Windows, a Desktop starts.

Notes:

- The Desktop is a Windows Server HSD, and is the only one available;
- The Desktop is a different VM from the one running the apps launched;
- Only happens in Receiver for Windows. If I start the app from the browser, it does not initiate the Desktop.

I've tried resetting the receiver and had no success. I've also followed [CTX139058](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX139058) without success.

The situation was also described [in this Citrix forum post](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/362979-xendesktop-76-application-also-opens-desktop/) but the answers weren't inconclusive.

#### Versions

- XenDesktop: 7.15
- StoreFront: 3.12
- Receiver for Windows: 4.7

Answer (score 0):

This behavior has stopped after an image update (I'm using MCS). I did not change any registry, configuration file or GPO!

I can't explain why but I will leave the answer because it may help someone.